# ¿Como agregar varios puertos al mismo contenedor de Docker?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, php7, docker-compose

Estoy ejecutando un contenedor docker que ejecuta un servicio de apache2.4 + PHP7 + MSSQL el asunto está en que quiero a ese mismo contenedor agregar puerto para ssh y ftp, como lo haría si ya cuando lo ejecuté por primera vez le declaré el 8080:80?

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo has creado el contenedor?, ¿puedes mostrar tu Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando un archivo de docker-composer, puedes poner esto, si ya el container se había creado no hay problemas, lo detienes y lo vuelves a levantar y se agregan los puertos nuevos:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
            - "./etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template"
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "2222:22"
            - "21:21"
```

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que no estés utilizando docker-compose y lo quieras llamar desde terminal con un Docker run, simplemente utiliza la opción -p tantas veces como te sea necesario.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -p X:22 -p Y:21 tu-imagen
```

También puedes utilizar la opción -P que es mucho más potente, ya que mapeara todos los puertos que tu imagen tenga expuestos a puertos que el host tenga libres(aunque luego tendrás que buscarlos haciendo un docker ps si no tienes un registrador o similar).

```
docker run -P tu-imagen
```

Finalmente otra opción es desplegarlo directamente en la red host para que los puertos expuestos del contenedor sean directamente los del host, aunque no suele ser lo recomendado por muchas razones (seguridad, abstracción, aislamiento ...)

```
docker run --network host tu-imagen
```

Si lo que quieres es añadirlos en caliente con el contenedor ejecutándose, probablemente no se pueda hacer, eso o que haya que montar un cacao bastante importante a nivel de sistema operativo. Mi consejo es que no lo hagas. Docker funciona precisamente para no tener que encariñarte con tus contenedores, o que no te de extrema pereza tener que cargarte una máquina virtual para que vuelva a funcionar. si deja de funcionar o simplemente (como en tu caso) quieres añadir una nueva funcionalidad rápida te lo cargas y lo vuelves a levantar.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.